# Pass arguments to docker build, but NOT via cli

Tags: docker, environment, docker-secrets

Is it possible to pass docker build `build-arg` arguments not as CLI parameters, but as environment variables for example?

I need to pass some sensitive information inside the build container, and if I do it using `--build-arg` it is getting exposed to other users of the system.

Is there a way to pass it in some other fashion?
(I know that I can do it using `docker-compose`, but I don't have `docker-compose` in that case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only possible via `--build-args`.

Sensitive information should not be passed as build args anyway, because as described in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)

> It is not recommended to use build-time variables for passing secrets like github keys, user credentials etc. Build-time variable
> values are visible to any user of the image with the docker history
> command.

Use `--secret` instead to pass sensitive info ([reference](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information)).

Comment: If it is possible using only `--build-args`, how `docker-compose` is doing it (under the hood)?

Comment: Not sure, but I think both `docker` and `docker-compose` use [Go SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/). Anyway, `docker-compose` does not build images, just runs them.

Comment: Sorry, I double checked, I was wrong about `docker-compose` and build ([here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#args) explained).

Comment: I read the referenced page through, but didn't find any explanation. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: That was just a side note, I referred to my earlier statement, that "docker-compose does not build images" - which was wrong, as you can have `build` section in your compose file and run `docker-compose build` - I wasn't at all aware of that. Linked doc explains how you pass build args.